# No sql root password set, can't connect to jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, root

I've never set a password for Microsoft SQL server and when I log in, I log in with localhost, I just write . and it connects me. Now I am building an application in java and I have to connect to my database but since I've never set out a password, I am stuck

```
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mpp");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword(" _____ ");
```

What do I write as password?

Comment: pass an empty string.. nothing much needed just _setPassword("");_

Comment: Please update your tags correctly as to which server you are using!!! You have state its mySQL in the question but in comments below you state its Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup your mySQL server with a password. Seen that it is best practice. You know security ans stuff :P

You wont be able to check what it is currently (depending on your install)

But you can reset it see the following answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371/how-do-i-retrieve-my-mysql-username-and-password) to reset for **mySQL**

Edit after your comment on using **Microsoft SQL** Server please see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196150/is-there-a-way-i-can-retrieve-sa-password-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: Problem is, I tried following the microsoft steps and I can't find my bin, I can't find anything. I have microsoft SQL server and everything is so messed up in the folder...

Comment: is there a way to check up my password? Maybe I have one?

Comment: Wait you said that you have mySQL server and in the comment above you say you have Microsoft SQL Server? Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 dataSource.setPassword(" _____ ");
```

to

```
 dataSource.setPassword("");
```